# How to detect a pause in input for UISearchBar/UITextField?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimer, uisearchbar

I have the following UISearchbar code:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    NSString* endpoint =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.someurl/",
                         [searchText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"]];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:endpoint];
    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    GTMHTTPFetcher* myFetcher = [GTMHTTPFetcher fetcherWithRequest:request];
    [myFetcher beginFetchWithDelegate:self didFinishSelector:@selector(searchResultsFetcher:finishedWithData:error:)];
}
```

I want to send this request after a pause in input and reset the timer everytime a character is hit.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It doesn't have to use NSTimer.

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
        {
           [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(request) object:nil];

          //.....

           [self performSelector:@selector(request) withObject:nil afterDelay:yourpausetime];

        }
```

Comment: Much more elegant solution than a NSTimer, I think. Could cause issues depending on the runloop and the user input or request, maybe? Hmm, not anymore so than a timer though

Comment: Nice! Here's another example with detailed comments: http://benedictcohen.co.uk/blog/archives/157

Comment: not working, the selector calls repeatedly even though we are cancelling (swift 3)

Answer (score 7):

In the `textDidChange` method create an NSTimer, say 2 seconds worth. If the timer already exists, invalidate and recreate the timer. (Untested code:)

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if (myTimer) {
        if ([myTimer isValid]) { [myTimer invalidate]; }
        [myTimer release], myTimer = nil;
    }
    myTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(userPaused:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO] retain];
}
```

When the user stops typing for 2 seconds, -userPaused: will be called and your timer will be automatically invalidated (although not nil). When the user starts typing again a new timer will be setup.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to adapt Sven Tan's answer to my existing code in Swift. In my case, I am sending the string to a method that loads the search results async. Additionally, I am not using the UISearchBar but rather a plain old UITextField.

```
var currentTempQuery = ""

...

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if let t = textField.text {
        let s: NSString = t
        let newString = s.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string).trim()

        NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget(self, selector:#selector(MyViewController.sendSearchRequest(_:)), object: currentTermQuery)

        // Don't replace currentTermQuery until after the cancelPreviousPerformRequestWithTarget call
        currentTermQuery = newString
        performSelector(#selector(MyViewController.sendSearchRequest(_:)), withObject: newString, afterDelay: 1)
    }
    return true
}
```

Here is the selector that is being called:

```
func sendSearchRequest(text: String?) {
    // Call async search method here...
}
```

The way that `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget` works is you need to pass the same target, selector, and object that was passed in the `performSelector` call in order for the previous request to be cancelled. In my implementation, since I am passing just a string, I need to preserve the current request string between calls so I can reference it to cancel requests.

The result works for typing and deleting characters into my UITextField. Only one search is sent per major search term change.

Like I said, similar to what Sven Tan posted but slightly different usage. Hopefully this helps some people out.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent code and working perfect for me. I found it here [Replacing an NSTimer with performSelector:withObject:afterDelay](http://benedictcohen.co.uk/blog/archives/157). **Thanks to *Ben* solution ... all bounties to him** i just copy it here to be found easy

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    //because the view can be unloaded we must store all data so that its state can be restored in viewDidLoad
    self.searchQuery = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    SEL fetchSearchResults = @selector(fetchSearchResults);

    //cancel the previous search request
    [[self class] cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:fetchSearchResults object:nil];    

    //perform the search in a seconds time. If the user enters addition data then this search will be cancelled by the previous line
    [self performSelector:fetchSearchResults withObject:nil afterDelay:1];

    return YES;
}

- (void)fetchSearchResults
{
    NSLog(@"performing search %@", self.searchQuery);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Block text input to your search and have an NSTimer call a selector. Show an indicator of some sort so the user doesn't think something is going wrong. When the selector fires give control back to the user to continue typing

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(targetMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Comment: A bunch of NSTimers will go off as the user types. How can I reset the NSTimer when a character is typed?

Comment: I take that back. invalidate only when you want to stop a timer from firing. The sample above has repeats:NO, so it'll fire once and it's done. =

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to block text input until the timer is done? would you be able to show me an example?

Comment: disable field or add a condition in textDidChange or ... Depends on the user experience you want. Imagine if I am just good and I want to type really fast? Maybe you should just init the server call after I stop typing for a specific time.