# Detect when stopped typing in UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

How should I go about detecting if typing has stopped in a `UITextField`? Should I use the `UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification` function of some sorts?  I a trying to create a instagram like search where it will display the results after a second of not typing.

Comment: What is it exactly you want to detect? When the user leaves the text field or when the user isn't typing anymore but the focus is still on the text field?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect a pause in input for UISearchBar/UITextField?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061377/how-to-detect-a-pause-in-input-for-uisearchbar-uitextfield)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This approach uses an NSTimer to schedule a search 1 second after the text field changes. If a new character is typed before that second is up, the timer starts over. This way, the search is only triggered starts after the last change.

**First things first, make sure the ViewController is conforms to the UITextFieldDelegate protocol:**

```
//
//  ViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>

@end
```

**Then, implement the timed search:**

```
//
//  ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textfield;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer * searchTimer;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // declare this view controller as the delegate
    self.textfield.delegate = self;

    // handle the change event (UIControlEventEditingChanged) by calling (textFieldDidChange:)
    [self.textfield addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

}

// reset the search timer whenever the text field changes
-(void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *)textField{

    // if a timer is already active, prevent it from firing
    if (self.searchTimer != nil) {
        [self.searchTimer invalidate];
        self.searchTimer = nil;
    }

    // reschedule the search: in 1.0 second, call the searchForKeyword: method on the new textfield content
    self.searchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0
                                                        target: self
                                                      selector: @selector(searchForKeyword:)
                                                      userInfo: self.textfield.text
                                                       repeats: NO];

}


- (void) searchForKeyword:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    // retrieve the keyword from user info
    NSString *keyword = (NSString*)timer.userInfo;

    // perform your search (stubbed here using NSLog)
    NSLog(@"Searching for keyword %@", keyword);
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 22):

This is how I did and it works for me in **Swift 3**

```
import UIKit

// don't forget to add UITextFieldDelegate
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

    var searchTimer: Timer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // declare textField as delegate
        self.textField.delegate = self

        // handle the editingChanged event by calling (textFieldDidEditingChanged(-:))
        self.textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidEditingChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    }

    // reset the searchTimer whenever the textField is editingChanged
    func textFieldDidEditingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {

        // if a timer is already active, prevent it from firing
        if searchTimer != nil {
            searchTimer?.invalidate()
            searchTimer = nil
        }

        // reschedule the search: in 1.0 second, call the searchForKeyword method on the new textfield content
        searchTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(searchForKeyword(_:)), userInfo: textField.text!, repeats: false)
    }

    func searchForKeyword(_ timer: Timer) {

        // retrieve the keyword from user info
        let keyword = timer.userInfo!

        print("Searching for keyword \(keyword)")
    }

}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 18):

swift
xcode - 10

```swift
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
               replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(
        withTarget: self,
        selector: #selector(self.getHintsFromTextField),
        object: textField)
    self.perform(
        #selector(self.getHintsFromTextField),
        with: textField,
        afterDelay: 0.5)
    return true
}

@objc func getHintsFromTextField(textField: UITextField) {
    print("Hints for textField: \(textField)")
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution

Comment: This is the answer

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSDate* timeStamp = [NSDate date];
    _timeStamp = timeStamp;
    CGFloat END_TYPING_TIME = 1.5;
    [self performSelector:@selector(endTyping:) withObject:timeStamp afterDelay:END_TYPING_TIME];
    return YES;
}

-(void) endTyping:(NSDate*) timeStamp {
    if ([timeStamp isEqualToDate:_timeStamp]) { //if it is the last typing...
        //TODO: do what ever you want to do at the end of typing...
    }
}
```

determine what is `END_TYPING_TIME` for your case...

the `_timeStamp` is a field of type `NSDate`.

Comment: what about using a NSTimer?

Comment: What is not working? It doesn't get to 'endTyping:'? It doesn't enter to the 'if' statement? It doesn't get to the delegate function (did you assigned the delegate field of the textField)?

Comment: @Yedidya it isnt getting to the endTyping function